# i have errors after compling my code on latex with this error message Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 103 producing 13 errors

Tags: beamer, itemize

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Darmstadt} 
  \usecolortheme{albatross} 
  \usefonttheme{serif} 
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{PORTFOLIO PRESENTATION}
\author{Uwajeh Nebune Joshua}
 \date{12/20/2020}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\section{Motivation}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}

\begin{itemize}
  \item As we are moving to the new era in IT that is Artificial intelligence. so aspiring be very tech-savvy  helps in motivating me as I was surprised first to see how a sample idea implemented through AI can change human life and make it simple 
  
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{artificial-intelligence.jpg}%

\end{itemize}

\begin{block}{Examples}
We can see how Alexa, Google, and Siri assist changed our life and we can simply control every device from our mobile and it also increases the security    
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\section{Project1 }

\subsection{Project1}

\begin{frame}{Project1}

\begin{itemize}
\item Prediction of crop yield:
I participated in a substantial increase in the  maize plant as a co-joined project  with the faculty of Agriculture and the faculty of computer science The objective of the work was to compare various data mining techniques which gives the maximum accuracy.
Data mining is the only way that assists to convert huge data into technologies and make them available to the
Farmers.
One of the major parameter which is used to increase crop production is considered; that is soil. Different
classification algorithms are applied to soil data set to predict its yield. The yield is predicted using KNN classification
and apriori algorithms.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\section{Project2}

\subsection{Project2}

\begin{frame}{Project2}

\begin{itemize}
\item Implementation of Clustering Algorithms and Comparative study between them:The objective of this project is to perform a comparative analysis of four clustering algorithms namely Kmeans
algorithm, Hierarchical, Density based and Fuzzy c-means algorithms. These algorithms are compared in terms of
efficiency and accuracy.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Participation}
\begin{frame}{Participation}
\begin{itemsize}
\item I have done these projects because this would help me in creating the base in my analytic and AI career. After all, big data is the building block of this as it helped me the train how to manage a large amount of data and also help me in gaining insights into the data. Then with the help of artificial intelligence, I can create the models and train them taking IT to a whole new level.
\end{itemsize}
\end{frame}

\section{Hobbies}

\subsection{Hobbies}

\begin{frame}{Hobbies}

\begin{itemize}I believe that no play and only work makes a Uwajeh dumb. So it is important to explore yourself and do various things that excite us like:- I love to cook when I have spare time. I love to read  books of all types and at last, love to swim and  play soccer.

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Skills and Knowledge}
\subsection{Skills and Knowledge}
\begin{frame}{Skills and Knowledge}
\begin{itemsize}
\item I have realized by working on these projects I have gained a lot of knowledge on Hadoop and how I can store the data and analyze it as now a day data is generated 20PB per day. While working on these I came to know various machine learning algorithms and the basic maths behind them which other people tend to skip. 

\end{itemsize}
\end{frame}

\section{New Skills}
\subsection{New Skills}
\begin{frame}{New Skills}
\begin{itemsize}
\item While working on these projects I realized that my favorite technology is Hadoop and Machine Learning. Also, I want to improve my skills in python as coding is the basic building block of every technology.  
\end{itemsize}
\end{frame}

\section{Thanking You}
\subsection{Thanking You}
\begin{frame}{Thanking You}
\begin{itemsize}
\item   THANK YOU

\end{itemsize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The document has several typos; e.g., replace all 8 instances of `{itemsize}` with `{itemize}`. The "Hobbies" frame lacks an `\item` directive after `\begin{itemize}`. The options `width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight` make little sense for a frame in which roughly two thirds of the avaiable space have already been spoken for.